# Getting Too many Open Files Error in logs

Tags: sql-server, ibm-mq, spring-jms, hikaricp

Recently we got "(Too many open files)" error in production and this leads to very high CPU spike(98%) on Linux machine and finally brought machine down. We have to reboot the machine to bring it back.

Flow of code is like this :-

**Consume message from one of IBM-MQ queue -> start processing it -> make some update entries into SQL-Server DB and commit the transaction.**

We are using Hikari for connection pool management and value is set as 30

```
hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
```

While checking the logs, i found following stack trace :-

```
2021-03-24T20:00:22.404 WARNING org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase Failed to open JAR [null]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/HikariCP-2.5.1.jar (Too many open files)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.openJARs(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3102)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3414)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1494)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1722)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control$1.run(ResourceBundle.java:2677)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control$1.run(ResourceBundle.java:2662)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2661)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException.buildMessage(JmqiException.java:428)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException.getMessage(JmqiException.java:543)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException.getMessage(JmqiException.java:515)
    at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getExSumm(JmqiTools.java:947)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.connect(WMQSession.java:387)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.<init>(WMQSession.java:331)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createSession(WMQConnection.java:909)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:896)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createSession(MQConnection.java:337)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createSession(SingleConnectionFactory.java:437)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getSession(CachingConnectionFactory.java:236)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:604)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:475)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:526)
    at com.test.config.messaging.MainframeMessageProducer.lambda$sendMessageToQueueWithHeaders$0(MainframeMessageProducer.java:120)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
    at com.test.config.messaging.MainframeMessageProducer.sendMessageToQueueWithHeaders(MainframeMessageProducer.java:118)
    at com.test.config.messaging.MainframeMessageProducer.sendMessageToMainframeQueue(MainframeMessageProducer.java:101)
    at com.test.config.messaging.MainframeMessageProducer$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f2d092d2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at com.test.common.aop.RecordTimingAspect.recordTimingAspect(RecordTimingAspect.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor505.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.test.config.messaging.MainframeMessageProducer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc5ae691.sendMessageToMainframeQueue(<generated>)
    at com.test.posting.GDISPurchasePostServiceImpl.postMessage(GDISPurchasePostServiceImpl.java:315)
    at com.test.posting.GDISPostingService.processMessage(GDISPostingService.java:56)
    at com.test.posting.GDISPostingService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3c0c40af.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at com.test.common.aop.CorrelationIdAspect.correlationIdAdvice(CorrelationIdAspect.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor554.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.test.posting.GDISPostingService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd870248.processMessage(<generated>)
    at com.test.posting.GDISPostingMessageListener.onMessage(GDISPostingMessageListener.java:167)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am confused here what leads to max open files error here :-

1. is it due to Hikari CP as this is first line we got as an error (java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/HikariCP-2.5.1.jar (Too many open files) ) ?
2. Is it due to IBM-MQ connection not available ?

Comment: Why don’t you just increase the number of maximum allowed open files on your OS?

Comment: Sounds like you're opening files and then failing to close them after use. Have you looked through your code to make sure that you're using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern so that AutoCloseable classes that wrap things like file handles are actually getting closed and disposed when they go out of scope?

Comment: @AttilaRepasi this is the first time we got issue in last 3 years and after rebooting it got fine. Since this is managed compute by other team, increasing the max connections would be difficult until we know what is real reason for it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning As we are using Hikari for connection pooling and Spring JPA as ORM tool, AFAIK opening and closing of connection as needed will be taken care by Hikari CP. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: That stack trace shows it failing to open .zip archive files (.jar files are .zip archive format with a different extension). Does your own code open any files from which data are read or written to? Is your own code closing those files after using them? Being on linux you could probably run `lsof -u YourProcessUserName` periodically to make sure that the list of files it keeps open doesn't keep growing over time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lsof command to LiSt Open Files.
It produces lots of output, so you'll want to capture and post process it ( eg grep or sort)
You can list open files by pid, userid, disk etc.

You might try lsof > before  wait...  lsof > after then use diff to see the differences